# Model.find() is not a function

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to query by finding the postalValue of the model but the error I am getting says there is no method **find()** .

Below is the error that I am getting when I am querying from the db.

> modelInstance.find({postalValue: 123344 }).then(model=>
>                 ^ TypeError: modelInstance.find is not a function
>       at Object. (/Users/biswajeet/Documents/webdriverio-test-framework/src/vendor/dataTest.js:44:15)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:754:12)
>       at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
>        at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)

```
const modelInstance = new RegisterModel({
   cred: {
       nameValue: 'Sample',
       emailValue: 'sample@gmail.com',
       passwordValue: 'sample122',
   },
   location: {
       addressValue: 'sample address',
       cityValue: 'sample',
       stateValue: 'sample',
       postalValue: 123344,
   },
   card: {
       cardName: 'Sample',
       cardNumber: 231232143,
       securityCode: 131,
       expirationMonth: 1,
       expirationYear: 2022,
   },
})
modelInstance.save(function (err) {
   console.log('@@@@@ Inside the callback ', err);
   if (err) {
       console.log('the error is ', err);
   }
   console.log('saved the model instance @@@@@@');
   console.log(modelInstance, '@@@@@Helllo@@@@@');
});
modelInstance.find({postalValue: 123344 }).then(model=>
   console.log('model@@@',model)
   )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In mongoose you have to do `RegisterModel.find()` because `modelInstance` is a instance of `RegisterModel` and the `find()` query operates on the model and not the model instance. Same thing applies for `findOne` and `findById`.

But for `save` you use `modelInstance.save` because you are actually saving the updated data. So, this will also force the mongodb to update the version value of the record i.e, `__v` if at least one property of that document is modified.